# Serialization optimization using Marshmallow, other solutions

Tags: python, optimization, serialization, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

This seems like it should be straightforward, but alas:

I have the following SQLAlchemy query object:

```
all = db.session.query(label('sid', distinct(Clinical.patient_sid))).all()
```

With the desired to serialize the output like [{'sid': 1}, {'sid': 2},...]

To do this, I am trying to use the following simple Marshmallow schema:

```
class TestSchema(Schema):
    sid = fields.Int()
```

However, when I do

```
schema = TestSchema()
result = schema.dump(record)
print result
pprint(result.data)
```

I get:

```
MarshalResult(data={}, errors={})
{}
```

for my output.

However, when I only select only one row from my query, e.g.,

```
one_record = db.session.query(label('sid', distinct(Clinical.patient_sid))).first()
```

I get the desired results:

```
MarshalResult(data={u'sid': 1}, errors={})
{u'sid': 1}
```

I DO know the query with .all() is returning data, since when I print it I get a list of tuples:

```
[(1L,), (2L,), (3L,), ...]
```

I am assuming Marshmallow can handle list of tuples, since, in the documentation to marshaling.py under the serialize method, it says: 
"Takes raw data (a dict, list, or other object) and a dict of..." However, this may be an incorrect assumption to think that lists of tuples could be classified as either "lists" or "other objects."

I like Marshmallow otherwise, and was hoping to use it as an optimization over serializing my SQLAlchemy output using an iterative method, like:

```
all = db.session.query(label('sid', distinct(Clinical.patient_sid)))

out = []
for result in all:
    data = {'sid': result.sid}
    out.append(data)
```

Which, for large records sets can take a while to process.

**EDIT**

Even if Marshmallow were able to serialize the entire record set as output by SQLAlchemy, I am not sure I would get any increase in speed, since it looks like it too iterates over the data.

Any suggestions for optimized serialization for the SQLAlchemy output, short of modifying the class definition for Clinical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to optimize my code was to go directly from my SQLAlchemy query object to a pandas data frame (I forgot to mention that I am doing some heavy lifting in pandas after I get my queried record set).

I thus was able to skip this step

```
out = []
for result in all:
    data = {'sid': result.sid
    out.append(data)
```

by using the `sql_read` method of Pandas as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_sql(all.statement, all.session.bind)
```

and then doing all my data manipulations and gyrations, thereby shaving off several seconds of processing time.